# How to check time in JavaScript on load

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that runs an if-else statement depending on the time of day. Example:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        var date = new Date();
        if(date.getHours() >= 15){
  //code to run
 } else {
  //other code to run
 }
}, 300000);
```

My problem is that it only refreshes to load what is in the if-else statement 300000 milliseconds(5 minutes) after the webpage is opened. However, I do not want to change that time to a very low digit and potentially cause issues from it refreshing so often. So the question is, can I make it check the time once on load, and then every 5 minutes after that?

Comment: yes, create a function, called something as "check" that does the `if else`, then run it on load and then add it as the callback function of the `setInterval` with 5 minutes as timeout

Comment: Make a function. Call this function on load, then again with an interval.

Comment: Adding the onload function that calls the interval function solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your logic in a separate function. Call it on load and inside the interval.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

  const myIntervalFun = (date) => {
  console.log(date.getHours())
    if (date.getHours() >= 15) {
      //code to run
    } else {
      //other code to run
    }
  }


  myIntervalFun(new Date())

  window.setInterval(function() {
    myIntervalFun(new Date())

  }, 3000);



});
```